# How to Download pdf using python selenium in google colab

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

```
!pip install selenium                      
!apt-get update  
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
i=1                                                                            
from selenium import webdriver           
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()           
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')   
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')        
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')            
import requests     
driver =webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)                      
driver.get("""https://www.faa.gov/airports/runway_safety/diagrams/""")  #Open website
search=driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="ident"]""") #It will go to search bar       
ICAO=input("ENTER 4 DIGIT ICAO CODE To Retrive Airport Diagram\t")      
search.send_keys(ICAO)# It will send input to search box            
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="searchDtpp"]/fieldset/div[4]/input""").click()  
#Search button    
links=driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="resultsTable"]/tbody/tr/td[8]/a""") #Find 
location of diagram                     
r = requests.head(links.get_attribute('href')) #give link of pdf                               
link=links.get_attribute('href')   
print(link)
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code on collab ?

Comment: after running the code Pdf file is not downloaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is webdriver setup in google colab. use this code instead.

```py
!pip install selenium
!apt-get update # to update ubuntu to correctly run apt install
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

### Edit:

To save in your google drive use this code:

- mount google drive

```py
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

- save pdf file

```py
response = requests.get(link)
path = "gdrive/My Drive/" + "filename" + ".pdf"
with open(path, "wb") as file:
  file.write(response.content)
```

Comment: But were it will store downloaded pdf you haven't mention any path

Comment: I am getting link through my code but how to download it

Comment: Where do you wanna save your pdf file? Google Drive?

Comment: First you should mount your google drive, after that you can save it using this script:
```response = requests.get(link)
path = base_path + "/" + filename + ".pdf"
with open(path, "wb") as file:
    file.write(response.content)```

Comment: Please notice **Edit** part in my answer. `response = requests.get(link)`

Comment: response = requests.get(link)
path = "gdrive/My Drive/" + "Aws training" + ".pdf"
with open(path, "wb") as file:
  file.write(response.content)

Comment: file didn't get store in given folder

Comment: This worked for me. Please share your full code.

Comment: This is my [code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Ym8k2bP2M_RjkzVRcbnEDz67TyfKn_8Q?usp=sharing) in google colab

Comment: its running but where it is storing the pdf file

Comment: In your Google Drive main folder. If you want to save it in another folder, you can use this:
`path = "gdrive/My Drive/folder_you_want/pdf_file.pdf"`